# Делегирование onClick не срабатыает для touch в Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создаю кнопку из префаба и хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку срабатывала моя функция. Нажатие обрабатывается правильно при тестировании на ПК, а на телефоне не реагирует на нажатие.

Внутри void Update() своего скрипта вот так создаю кнопку и делегирую обработку клика на свою функцию:

```
 UnityEngine.UI.Button choice = Instantiate(button) as UnityEngine.UI.Button;
 choice.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ChoiceSelected(choiceId); });
```

Вот дальше идёт моя функция, которая срабатывает на ПК:

```
public void ChoiceSelected(int id)
{
UnityEngine.UI.Text Text = Instantiate(text) as UnityEngine.UI.Text;
}
```

Подозреваю, что дело в отлавливании onClick для touch. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Я бы избегал добавления делегата через код в слушатель `onClick`. Пару раз сталкивался с тем что, так или иначе эта косячит.

Comment: А как мне тогда лучше "отправить" срабатывание тача по кнопке к моей функции? Тут ещё получается, что я их создаю программно, и мне нужно знать по какой кнопке было нажатие...

Comment: Судя по документации `onClick` работает только для мыши.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, onClick() работает для телефона. Заново пересоздала EventSystem и всё заработало.